# Dependencies of the solution folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory, solution, vsx

I create some visual studio extension and i create solution folder programmatically.
But i don't know how to create a dependency one solution folder from another solution folder?
Can any help me with this problem? Thanks!

```
|--- SolutionFolder
|          |--- SolutionFolder
|          |--- SolutionFolder
|--- SolutionFolder
```

Here is my code:

```
(object sender, EventArgs args) =>
{
    Guid slnFldrGuid = new Guid("2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8");
    Guid iidProject = typeof(IVsHierarchy).GUID;

    IVsSolution solution = GetService<IVsSolution, SVsSolution>();
    IVsHierarchy parent = UIShellUtilities.GetSelectedHierarchy();
    IVsHierarchy nested = null;

    IntPtr project = IntPtr.Zero;
    int canceled = 0;

    if ((null != solution) && (null != parent))
    {
        IVsProjectFactory factory = null;

        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(solution.GetProjectFactory(
            0, new Guid[] { slnFldrGuid }, null, out factory));

        try 
        {
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(factory.CreateProject(
                null, null, "New My Folder", 0, ref iidProject,  out project, out canceled));

            if (project != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                nested = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(project, typeof(IVsHierarchy)) as IVsHierarchy;

                Debug.Assert(nested != null, "Nested hierarchy could not be created");
                Debug.Assert(canceled == 0);
            }
        } finally
        {
            if (project != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.Release(project);
        }

        uint itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT;

        // Link into the nested VS hierarchy.
        //ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(nested.SetProperty(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ParentHierarchy, parent));
        //ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(nested.SetProperty(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ParentHierarchyItemid, (object)itemid));
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating nested solution folders is considerably easier using the automation model EnvDTE, which can be used also from packages.

See:

How to create a solution folder inside another solution folder
http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2013/12/03/how-to-create-a-solution-folder-inside-another-solution-folder/